# Drag windows with right mouse button in Linux Mint KDE

Tags: window-manager, window-management

I like how you can drag a window with the cursor anywhere in the window by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + left mouse.

1. Is it possible to drag a window by pressing and holding just the right mouse button?
2. Minimize window pressing right mouse + left mouse
3. Close window by pressing right mouse + middle mouse

**N.B. This is all without holding down any keys on the keyboard.**

Comment: Do not know for pt. 1., but for 2. and 3. a compromise would perhaps be to use mouse gestures in combination with wmctrl and [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml).